# javax.faces. context-param

Tags: jsf-2, web.xml

Tell me please can i set all parameters in "javax.faces."(web.xml) with settings like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

this settings are mean some thing or not? I just seen it in one place and i have no exception with this when i start application, but i can't understand what it mean. Tryed to browse internet for answer but without fortune.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way. You *really* need to set them **individually**. Note that there are also context parameters which doesn't accept a boolean value at all. So your theoretical approach would have failed for them anyway.

For an overview of all available standard JSF context parameters, read chapter 11.1.3 "Application Configuration Parameters" of the [JSF specification (for evaluation)](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html). For an online copy in flavor of a HTML page, check [JBoss AS 6 manual chapter 5.1](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/JSF_Guide/en-US/html/jsf.reference.html).

Note that JSF implementations have also their own specific set of context parameters, such as [`com.sun.faces` ones for Mojarra](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/JavaServerFacesRI#JavaServerFacesRI-Whatcontextparametersareavailableandwhatdotheydo%3F) and [`org.apache.myfaces` ones for MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html).

Comment: BalusC you are so PRO. :) Thnak you!  **Note that there are also context parameters which don't accept a boolean value at all** i think about it, but i decided that i know not all about it, and it may work for all boolean parameters for example.